# Run Python Script on Laravel Controller

Tags: python, laravel

im trying to run a python file on a laravel controller.
I have this code

```
class MLCosineSimilarity extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        try {
            $pythonPath = base_path('venv/bin/python3.10'); // Adjust to the correct path
            $scriptPath = base_path('cousine.py'); // Adjust to the correct path

            $commands = [
                $pythonPath,
                $scriptPath
            ];

            $process = new Process($commands);
            $process->run();

            if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
            }

            return $process->getOutput();

        } catch (ProcessFailedException $e) {
            // Handle the error here
            echo "An error occurred while running the process: " . $e->getMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Catch other exceptions that may occur
            echo "An unexpected error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And i have a route api that calls that function. The problem is that when i try to access the API route i get everytime an error line 1, in import matplotlib ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Im using a virtual environment that is localted at venv (in the root of laravel project).

Can someone help?

Comment: pip install matplotlib?

Comment: I have alk the modules that need installed. If i Run the script from the terminal ir works

Comment: Have you tried to active the venv before your command in php? 
In this link there is an example: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/running-python-script-from-venv

Comment: yes i have, still the same issue regarding the modules